# view upload image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have program to upload image and display result from upload. But when I display image only show path image not image. And in database I save by full_path. Please tell me code how to display image from my code.

Here is the controller:

```
function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100000';
        $config['max_width']  = '10240';
        $config['max_height']  = '7680';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            print_r($this->upload->data());
            $datafoto=$this->upload->data();
            $nm_file = time().$datafoto['full_path'];
            $this->load->model('mkegiatan');
            $this->mkegiatan->update_foto($nm_file);
            copy('images/'.$datafoto['full_path'], 'images/'.$nm_file);
        }
    }
```

Here is the view:

```
 <?php echo e($kegiatan->image) ; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you said you see just image path and not image itself? Try to replace this:

```
<?php echo e($kegiatan->image) ; ?>
```

With this:

```
<img src="/<?php echo e($kegiatan->image) ; ?>" />
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as a solution if this works for you. Thanks.

Comment: thank you but when i try inspect img become like this <img src="1399477397D:/xampp/htdocs/tkd/images/36.png">

Comment: So you have to get your full path from the database and put it into SRC of the IMG tag.

Comment: i am sorry img become like this <img src="/1399477397D:/xampp/htdocs/tkd/images/36.png">

Comment: I am not sure what is $kegiatan in your code. Provide full code to figure out.

Comment: sorry i don't know what is 1399477397.

Comment: So you have to figure out with this first before posting your question. This is your code and nobody can see it for now.

Comment: hi pavel its already solved. thank you and  i am sorry about that